# MODx. Empty partition / manager

Tags: syntax-error, modx

Lost resource tree under /manager. **MODX Revolution 2.2.5-pl (advanced)**. 
Log in to the admin panel is obtained, but the admin is only the top toolbar.

[image]

In the core/cache/logs/error.log:

```
[2013-03-21 11:18:22] (ERROR @ /index.php) `` is not a valid integer and may not be passed to makeUrl()
```

Ie there is no error on the part of a PHP /manager/index.php.

Firebug after login shows:

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
...rer:this.renderNoteCell.createDelegate(this)]});this.grid_panel=new Ext.grid.Gri...
modx.t...tory.js (строка 806)

ReferenceError: _ is not defined
params[this.paramNames.topic] = '/ys/user-' + MODx.user.id + '/';
modx.js (строка 820)

TypeError: MODx.user is undefined
params[this.paramNames.topic] = '/ys/user-' + MODx.user.id + '/';
modx.js (строка 820)
```

Chrome shows:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Not Authorized)  
http://example.com/connectors/lang.js.php?    
ctx=mgr&topic=topmenu,file,resource,setting,gallery:default&action=70
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined modx.tree.directory.js:806
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined modx.localization.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined modx.js:820
```

Error found on this material, all the writing that the matter compress_js and compress_css.
I adjusted the values ​​from 1 to 0 (Table modx_system_settings). Deleted cache. I go to the admin panel - nothing has changed. In the cache now:
core/cache/system_settings/config.cache.php

```
 'compress_css' => '0',
 'compress_js' => '0',
```

Why Chrome is responsible Not Authorized not clear, as if I logged, but MODx does not understand.
I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Also turn off 'concat_js'.

Comment: Where this option turn off? can't find where it is

Comment: In system settings or in `core/cache/system_settings/config.cache.php` if dont access to system settings in admin panel.

Comment: in the core/cache/system_settings/config.cache.php has no option concat_js. I added it), nothing has changed. still does not work. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You've done an advanced install and moved one or both the manager and core directories?

First, double check all the paths in core/config, the 2 config.core.php in your site root & manager directories, review all this: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Hardening+MODX+Revolution

if you have moved the core out of above the web root, check your php settings & make sure php can read/write to those directories I had to implicitly add the path to the core's parent directory in my php config. [I was getting the same error as you]

Also, js & css compression hasn't been a problem for a while. 2.2.1 I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue. Please double-check all the config files, especially config paths. My task was domain transfering from  web to localhost. There are two imoprtant cases - firstly, check paths(especially pay attention on the slashes, under Windows you have different ones, btw you can / and \ at the same times, it depends). Secondly, there are some troubles with suhosin extension but this wasn't my case. Hope it helps.